# Python: Print Lines without Input Being broken up

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I am trying to make a simple multi-threaded command prompt for a small AngularJS app I'm running.

In this prompt, I want to type in a command without it being broken up by output, like below:

```
Output
More output HTTP 1.0
HTTP Request from 127.0.0.1 for /img/foo.png - 200
> Humble command I'm ty-OH NO BUT MORE OUTPUT
SUCH ANNOYING OUTPUT FOR FAVICON.ICO - 404
-ping.. Dang it.
```

Instead, I want it like this:

```
Output
More output HTTP 1.0
HTTP Request from 127.0.0.1 for /img/foo.png - 200
OH NO BUT MORE OUTput and it's not breaking up what
you're typing... :/ - favicon.ico 404 btw...
> Humble command I'm typing that's not broken up
```

I'm not sure if it's possible on the command prompt, and if needed, I might just import pygame or take a look at pyglet if needed, but I believe that the command prompt would be better for my purpose.

I hope I explained it for you, but if you need more information, please ask below!

*Using Python 3.x*

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/MathManiac0/de5a717185ed4cded8c7)

[image: What it looks like]

this is what it looks like

**Edit:** I added cmd.Cmd to be my command prompt and did what J. F. Sebastian told me to do, but it acts.. strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid output from other threads interrupting your input, organize your script to perform standard I/O only in the main thread e.g., replace `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` with file-like objects that queue writes and consume the queue when you've done input:

```
import sys
from queue import Queue, Empty

class QueuedFile:
   def __init__(self, queue):
       self.queue = queue
   def write(self, text):
       self.queue.put(text)
   def flush(self):
       pass # noop

q = Queue()
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = QueuedFile(q)

# print from multiple threads while accepting input...

# print queued output
while True:
    try:
        sys.__stdout__.write(q.get(block=False))
    except Empty:
        break # no more output
```

Comment: Interesting... Is there a module for that, or would I need to make it?

Comment: My head is thumping right now, but you've been a great help! I'll go and study the queue module...

Comment: I've been looking it up and why do you have a try/except block when you can just leave the `block` arg to be True?

Comment: @MathManiac: To break the loop when the available queued output is exhausted. I assume there is also an outer loop i.e., you read input without interruptions then you print output so far then you read input again, etc.

Comment: I ran into a problem: sys.__stdout__ and sys.__stderr__ return None, but I only figured that out by looking into the sys docs and returning sys.stderr back to normal. **Edit:** I don't know why it's not normal, but I'll set it back to normal at the beginning of my program, see if it works.

Comment: @MathManiac: save `sys.stdout` before replacing it with `QueuedFile(q)`. And use the saved value instead of `sys.__stdout__` later.

Comment: @MathManiac: Try to limit your questions to a single issue per question. [Create a *minimal* but complete code example that demonstrates the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it as a separate question (link to the current question for the context if necessary).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to run the python script as a background process:

```
>python yourScript.py &
>now it won't interrupt you but you'll have to pipe output to a file if you want to read it
```

The `&` is what does that.

If you want to run the script without output in the background *from within Python*, I would consider using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: While this doesn't solve the problem I want to solve,+1 for the info! I might use it later!