# How to print output without interrupting user input?

Tags: python, io

I'm trying to create a command line chat application. I intend for the user to be able to receive a message while the user is in the process of typing a message without the message being broken up.

For example, if my program is:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def print_received_message():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        print(counter)
        counter += 1
        sleep(1)

t = Thread(target = print_received_message)
t.start()

while True:
    my_message = input('>')
    print(my_message)
```

And I am currently 2 seconds into typing my message, I hope to see the following:

```
0
1
2
> Currently typ
```

And if I finish typing and sending my message after 4 seconds I hope to see:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Currently typing
>
```

However, I am currently seeing:

```
0
> 1
Cur2
rent3
ly4
5
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173856/python-print-lines-without-input-being-broken-up) post, but the solution queues output until I have finished my input, whereas I wish for the output to be printed in live time.

I have considered: when a message arrives, save what the user has inputted to far, clear the line, print the new message, then print the saved message progress. However, getting user input without the user pressing enter first seems difficult, and this solution feels hackish overall.

Is there any way I can achieve this goal, or is it infeasible?

Comment: I would suggest against using cmd to implement a thing like this, since you'd have to handle things like stdin and stdout properly to have that GUI feeling you need. Try to implement it with a GUI instead.

Comment: `input()` wasn't create for things like this. It would need modules like `curses` `urwid` to create `TUI` (Text User Interface). Or  use any `GUI` (Graphics User Interface) like `tkinter`, `PyQt`

Comment: you have two problems: **1.** receive remote data when when user uses `input()`, **2.** display it in correct place - because you can't move new text above `input. And TUI may resolve some of them.

Comment: @ thanks all for the suggestions. `urwid` would seem to solve my problem, but it lacks Windows support. I've decided to go the Tkinter route which seems to be the easiest to implment, but I'm leaving this question open out of curiosity.